# Angular js template symbol bug

Tags: javascript, angularjs, django-templates

I'm working with Angular and Django, so I changed the angular symbols to "[[ ]]", works fine if I only want to display the variable.

The problem appears when I need to an Angular variable as a parameter to a function.

Ex:

```
angular_var = 5
```

HTML: `<button ng-click="someFunc([[angular_var]])"></button>`

Renders: `<button ng-click="someFunc(5)"></button>`

But the values received by the function comes in 2 arrays = `[[5]]`

Comment: The correct usage is `ng-click="someFunc(angular_var)"`, not `ng-click="someFunc([[angular_var]])"`.

Comment: Thanks, the value was rendering someFunc(angular_var), I thought was wrong. -.-